# As Json deserialize

Tags: json, serialization

How to competently deserialize the following text. The coordinates change, and there may be other numbers in the current branch. Appeal as a static class is not possible. But how to make through the dictionary.

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "data": {
        "1_667": {
            "x": "1",
            "y": "667",
            "Type": 10,
        },
        "1_671": {
            "x": "1",
            "y": "671",
            "Type": 10,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: programming language C#

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make through the dictionary"?